# Питон не понятный синтаксис

Tags: python, синтаксис

Что значит ['*'] в этом коде?

````
for link in data:
        if link['*'] not in seeLink:
            linkToPars.append(link['*'])
            print(link['*'])
```
````

Comment: атрибут с именем `*`

Comment: Учитывая, что вы не назвали, к каким классам принадлежат переменные, используемые в коде, вариантов может быть масса. Если все переменные являются объектами стандартных типов, то скорее всего `link` - это словарь, который содержит строковый ключ `'*'`. А в общем случае `link` - это объект какого-то класса, для которого как-то реализован метод `__getitem__`. При получении ключа `'*'` он может хоть число пи начать вычислять - это зависит от задумки разработчика конкретного класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это доступ к значению по ключу (в случае dict):

```
acronyms = dict()
acronyms['*'] = "any"
acronyms['py'] = "python"

for key in acronyms:
    print(key, type(key), acronyms[key], acronyms.__getitem__(key))
    
class Acr(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

acr = Acr()
acr.py = 'python'
print(acr['py'])
```

Вывод:

```
* <class 'str'> any
py <class 'str'> python
python
```

Answer (score 1):

> Что значит ['*'] в этом коде?

Если предположить, что `data` это список словарей - то в каждом словаре мы ищем ключ который равен `'*'`

В другом контексте - это синтаксическая ошибка.